# From React-native-navigation v1 to react-native-navigation v2 for existing project

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Is their any way to convert react-native-navigation v1 project to react-native-navigation v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're experimenting with an adapter that allows you to use existing v1 api with v2.
https://github.com/wix-playground/react-native-navigation-v1-v2-adapter

We were able to convert a very large project to v2 in a few minutes. I would recommend using it as a temporary step while you transition to v2.
Whenever you use a v1 api, it prints to log the equivalent v2 api which lets you convert your app at your own pace.

Comment: Hello @guy.gc , I am getting this follow error when I try to run react-native run-ios: 

The following build commands failed:
 CompileC /Users/*/test/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeNavigation.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeNavigation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTHelpers.o RCTHelpers.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Seems like RNN2 have some troubles with RN 0.55.4.

Comment: solved out doing this:
React/Views/RCTFont.h : line 21
-RCT_EXTERN BOOL RCTHasFontHandlerSet(); //original
+RCT_EXTERN BOOL RCTHasFontHandlerSet(void); //changed